# Inherit template in odoo 16

Tags: odoo

Here this template in odoo 16 hr_holidays showing  a calendar in dashboard. i want to remove the dashboard calendar in inherited custom mdule. how can I do that please help me.
here is the default template

```
xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="hr_holidays.CalendarRenderer" owl="1">
        <div class="o_timeoff_calendar">
            <TimeOffDashboard t-if="showDashboard" employeeId="employeeId"/>
            <t t-call="web.CalendarRenderer"/>
        div>
    t>
templates>
```

I inherit this view and remove calendar but its not working

```
<templates xml:space="preserve">
<t t-name="hr_holidays.CalendarRenderer" t-extend="hr_holidays.CalendarRenderer">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_timeoff_calendar']" position="replace"/>
t>
templates>
```

I also add this template in manifest

```
'web.assets_backend': [
    'custom_leave_management/static/src/views/inherit_calendar_view.xml',
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `inherit` instead of `extend`

To replace the div, use the [extension inheritance (in-place transformation)](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/reference/frontend/qweb.html#id8).

***Example:***

```xml
<t t-inherit="hr_holidays.CalendarRenderer" t-inherit-mode="extension">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='o_timeoff_calendar']" position="replace"/>
</t>
```